# ¿Sería válida una etiqueta acerca de El Quijote?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Revisando las preguntas, hay cerca de 90 que mencionan la obra de Cervantes. Sé que luego puede prestarse para generar etiquetas de otras obras o autores, pero siendo esta *la obra magna* de la lengua española (desde que surgieron las jarchas hasta las mejores respuestas del sitio), debería tenerla.
Si bien este hace parte de literatura, España y (parte de) español medieval, su importancia le merecería la etiqueta 
Gracias por sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: Nótese que he votado la pregunta porque me parece interesante, no porque esté especialmente a favor de crear la etiqueta propuesta. Si alguien está a favor, que lo indique en una respuesta para que pueda ser votada (puede ser el propio OP).

Comment: 90 por [quijote](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=quijote) y 20 más por [quixote](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=quixote). Creo que el tag [literatura](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literatura) es suficiente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No creo que sea apropiado crearla.

Este sitio es sobre el idioma español y, por tanto, el foco está en la lingüística, la sintaxis, la gramática, etc. Una etiqueta específica sobre El Quijote pondría el acento en literatura, que es algo que no tratamos aquí directamente (pertenecería a otros sitios como [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com)).

Tal y como se comenta en [Privileges > Create tags](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. When you choose to create a new tag, you're asking a question in a topic that nobody before you (on this site, at least) ever has.

Las preguntas sobre el idioma español relacionadas con El Quijote yo creo que están más que bien etiquetadas con [español-medieval](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espa%c3%b1ol-medieval) y similares.

---

El homenaje que sí podríamos hacer a este libro es solicitar un cambio del nombre de la medalla [Strunk & White](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) (editar 80 publicaciones) por algo tipo Cervantes o Covarrubias. En Stack Overflow en español lo pedimos y finalmente [se implementó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2079/83).

Comment: Which does raise the question of why we have badges all named in English on this site.

Comment: @mdewey not sure if SE would allow this step ahead. But we also didn't think all-Spanish tags would be available and now we have that. I would suggest opening the debate in a new question here in Meta.

Comment: See here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344643/is-there-any-policy-reason-why-language-sites-have-badges-named-in-english

Comment: ¿Y no se deberían etiquetar con una nueva tag "español-renacentista"?

Comment: Bueno, lo decía porque lo de etiquetar El Quijote como medieval siempre me ha parecido sorprendente.

Comment: @Charo pues tienes toda la razón, no había caído en que El Quijote ya sale del español medieval

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming':  Bueno, es algo que llevo pensando desde hace tiempo. No lo había dicho antes porque no me da mucho tiempo de participar aquí. Y creo que hay otras preguntas sobre "español-renacentista" como aquella de los términos para la suma (y probablemente otras que desconozco).

Comment: Sobre El Quijote hay quien piensa que ya es un poco barroco, sobre todo la segunda parte (pero medieval seguro que no, ni siquiera en sentido "figurado").

Comment: En realidad es natural: las grandes obras de arte siempre son rompedoras en algún aspecto (y El Quijote creo que lo es en muchos).

Answer (score 2):

La creación de la etiqueta tiene sus pro y sus contra, los cuales (a mi parecer) serían los siguientes (aunque en la pregunta ya había ingresado parte de ellos)

Pros :

- Es la obra literaria más conocida del idioma
- Se hace notoria su influencia 4 siglos después de su publicación
- Al menos 90 referencias entre preguntas y respuestas del sitio realizan mención de la obra

Contras :

- Se presta para incluir otras etiquetas de obras (Si está *Don Quijote*, ¿Por qué no *El cid*, *La segunda Celestina*, *Cien años de soledad*, *La ciudad y los perros* u otras? -Ante esa pregunta la respuesta básica serían los puntos previos - )
- El énfasis del sitio es del idioma, no tanto su literatura (Si bien la literatura es parte importante del mismo)
- Se pueden plantear las preguntas con otras etiquetas desde su enfoque idiomático

Cualquier pro o contra que consideren importante en esta discusión, bienvenido sea.

En caso tal que no se considere necesaria la etiqueta planteada, quizá pueda contemplarse las etiquetas Español_áurico, Español_medio o Siglo_de_oro (La o es inclusiva, valga la aclaración). Pero eso será tema de otro debate.

Comment: Técnicamente, son 27 las preguntas que mencionan Quijote. En total hay 90 publicaciones con la referencia.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en ver si se puede poner una etiqueta que abarque el castellano de esas fechas

Comment: Por lo que leo, podría ser algo así como [Español medio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Español_medio).